# SQL procedure AND OR statement

Tags: sql-server

Im declaring two variables called Itemcode & Itemcode2. 
Im trying to pull data that either contains Itemcode OR Itemcode2.

Something is wrong with my syntax, but I cannot see what. I've been awake for to long.....

**Here is the problem line:**

```
(AND d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode OR d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode2)
```

**Here is the entire procedure:**

```
USE [EnterpriseLive]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[web_GetReviewTimesheetWIPDetailsByActivity4]    Script Date: 12/03/2015 11:07:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[web_GetReviewTimesheetWIPDetailsByActivity4]
@Company char(15),
@ItemCode char(15),
@ItemCode2 char(15),
@StartYear smallint,
@EndYear smallint,
@ResourceCode char(15),
@ClientCode char(15),
@JobCode char(15),
@ActivityCode char(15)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
w.LinkNumber,
w.SequenceNo,
w.TransactionDate AS TransactionDate,
w.JobCode AS JobCode,
j.JobName AS JobName,
c.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
c.ClientName AS ClientName,
w.ResourceCode AS ResourceCode,
r.ResourceName AS ResourceName,
d.ActivityCode AS ActivityCode,
(CASE d.PhaseNumber
WHEN 0 THEN d.JobDetailDescription
ELSE (SELECT JobDetailDescription
 FROM JobDetail
WHERE  Company = d.Company
AND JobCode = d.JobCode
AND PhaseNumber = d.PhaseNumber
AND JobDetailLevel = 1) + ': ' + d.JobDetailDescription
END) AS ActivityName,
w.JobSequenceNo AS JobSequenceNo,
NULL AS NCTimeCode,
(CASE w.Billable WHEN 1 then w.HoursWorked ELSE 0 END) AS BillableHours,
(CASE w.Billable WHEN 0 then w.HoursWorked ELSE 0 END) AS NonBillableHours,
w.HoursWorked AS TotalHours,
w.CostBase AS Cost,
(CASE w.Billable when 1 then w.CostBase + w.MarkupBase ELSE 0 END) AS Charge,
(CASE w.Billable when 0 then w.CostBase + w.MarkupBase ELSE 0 END) AS NonBillableClientCharge,
w.WIPNarrative AS WIPNarrative
FROM WIPDetails w
INNER JOIN JobHeader j ON w.Company = j.Company AND w.JobCode = j.JobCode
INNER JOIN Client c ON j.Company = c.Company AND c.ClientCode = j.JobClientCode
INNER JOIN JobDetail d ON w.Company = d.Company AND w.JobCode = d.JobCode AND w.JobSequenceNo = d.JobSequenceNo
INNER JOIN Resource r ON w.Company = r.Company AND r.ResourceCode = w.ResourceCode
WHERE  w.Company = @Company     
AND TransactionSource = 'TIME'
AND JobOverhead = '0'  
(AND d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode OR d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode2)
AND w.TimesheetYear >= @StartYear and w.TimesheetYear <= @EndYear
AND r.ResourceCode IN (SELECT val FROM dbo.web_GetResourceCodeForWIPDetails(@Company, @ResourceCode))
AND c.ClientCode IN (SELECT val FROM dbo.web_GetClientCodeForWIPDetails(@Company, @ClientCode))
AND j.JobCode IN (SELECT val FROM dbo.web_GetJobCodeForWIPDetails(@Company, @JobCode))
ORDER BY w.TransactionDate, ResourceName, JobName, ActivityName

END
```

Comment: (AND d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode OR d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(AND d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode OR d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode2)
```

change to -

```
AND d.ActivityCode IN (@ItemCode, @ItemCode2)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, just use `AND (d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode OR d.ActivityCode = @ItemCode2)` (note the placement of the `AND`, which was the problem with the original syntax.) I'd agree the `IN` is more concise and readable, though.